# SELECT DISTINCT sum in google sheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets

i've a sheet like this:

| Month(Col11) | Team (Col2) |
| --- | --- |
| 03 | luna |
| 03 | luna |
| 04 | pippo |
| 04 | gigi |
| 04 | luna |
| 04 | gigi |
| 04 | pippo |
| 04 | luna |
| 04 | luna |
| 04 | pippo |
| 04 | pippo |
| 04 | grisbi |
| 04 | grisbi |
| 05 | luna |
| 05 | luna |
| 05 | pippo |
| 05 | pippo |
| 05 | grisbi |
| 05 | grisbi |

i need the sum of unique of each month, a result like this:

| Month(Col11) | Sum of unique (Col2) |
| --- | --- |
| 03 | 1 |
| 04 | 4 |
| 05 | 3 |

i try with:
=QUERY(database_tornei!A:K;"select Col11,count(Col2) group by Col11")
But i've the sum of all Teams in Col2.
Don't know how to use dinstinct in query :(

Comment: Are the entries in Col11 (e.g., 03, 04, 05) true numbers or strings? They have a leading zero and they are aligned left in the column, which leads me to believe they are strings. Is that correct? Also, if you plan to keep data for more than one calendar year, how will you distinguish the "03" for March 2021 from the "03" of March 2022? It seems to me that Col11 should include both month and year.

Comment: If you don't know how to test whether data is a number or a string, just go to an empty cell somewhere and type something like this: =ISNUMBER(K2)  If this comes back TRUE, the content of that cell is a number; if FALSE, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your existing `query()` in another `query()` like this:

`=query( query(A1:K, "select K, A, count(K) where K is not null group by K, A", 1), "select Col1, count(Col3) group by Col1", 1 )`

This will get the count of uniques per month.

Answer (score 0):

I asked some questions in the comments below the original post, but haven't heard back yet. So I'll just provide two versions of a formula, one for each case.

If your data in Col11 is text/strings, use this:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(UNIQUE({K2:K,B2:B}),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Month', COUNT(Col1) 'Count Unique'"))`

If your data in Col11 is real numbers, use this:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(UNIQUE({TEXT(K2:K,"00"),B2:B}),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col1 <> '00' GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Month', COUNT(Col1) 'Count Unique'"))`

In this second case, you need to convert the numbers to text in order to produce a format with a leading zero as shown in your post example.

This still does not account for distinguishing the months from different years. If your sheet will only ever have months from a single year, you don't need to worry about it. But if you will keep cumulative data that spans more than one calendar year, you will want to change the format of Col11 to something like this:

03 [2021]

04 [2021]

...

12 [2021]

01 [2022]

02 [2022]

03 [2022]

If you decide to do it this way, you can still use the first formula I provided above. It will just assure that months from different years stay separate.

Comment: Month(Col11) numbers

Comment: My post above provides all variations you'd need. Just use the second formula option, if you are sure your Col11 data is numeric. I still strongly suggest that you make it non-numeric (i.e., string), however, and include the year as shown above. If you decide to do that, use the first formula version.